# Streamlit importing HDF5 FILES

Tags: deep-learning, model, hdf5, streamlit, densenet

I am developing a car damage assessment project using streamlit.
I have trained three densenet models and also yolov5 model for bounding boxes.
Now i have connected with frontend using streamlit application and want to deloy that application in their cloud platform [streamlit cloud](https://docs.streamlit.io/images/streamlit-community-cloud/deploy-an-app.png).

For this application to be deployed my project needs to be on github. But i cannot upload my hdf5 files into github as they are very large. I uploaded into drive and tried like this:

```
@st.cache_resource
def load_models():
    stage1 = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jwz47Yu7uUmPPtmCrzdF3q10lHtkuVyy/view?usp=drive_link'
    stage2 = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wpjWBxuhxQLE-L5GcmIIiI7O_TaciIK/view?usp=drive_link'
    stage3 = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_4drud9QqAjzZzZ4g1Q8bFG_FUixw-A7/view?usp=drive_link'
    model1 = load_model(stage1)
    model2 = load_model(stage2)
    model3 = load_model(stage3) 
    
    return model1,model2,model3
```

Any help on how can i load my models with the links so that i can upload on github.